# How to add permissions for webrtc to Gecko View

Tags: mobile, permissions, gecko

I've created an android project & implement GeckoView instead of WebView. 
In manifest I've added

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

But when I try to open a site with camera permission nothing happens.

Comment: Have you found any solution Dimitris? I am trying to help someone with a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56709874/geckoview-get-microphone-permission). Also enjoy the upvotes! =P

Comment: @buræquete No I didn't find any solutions yet :/ I had to stay with Chromium webview for my work.