# Geckoview get microphone permission

Tags: android, firefox, gecko, geckoview

I am trying to use the audio recording feature from a website inside a GeckoView element.
Therefore I set the permission inside AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

When I now try to record the audio on the website, an HTML PopUp (which is part of the website, not a feature of the browser) tells me that I need to give permission. I can't do anything else - it's just a note without buttons.

On the other hand: when I use the regular Firefox browser, the browser asks me if I want to grant permission to my mic for this website while this HTML PopUp is shown.

I don't get asked that by GeckoView and therefore need to find a way to grant permission to use the mic for this website inside GeckoView.
Do I need to give permission inside GeckoView? I looked up the documentation on permissions of GeckoView but could not get it to work (probably because of my basic coding knowledge).

Highly appreciate any help!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: "it tells me that I need to give permission" -- can you explain this in greater detail? What is "it", and how is it requesting for permission? If you are referring into an in-GeckoView popup, that might be carried over from the browser experience.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear: when I open the website in question in regular Firefox and want to access the audio recording feature, a popup (HTML / part of the website) appears and tells me to give permission to the mic. At the same time Firefox asks me if I want to grant permission for this website. Inside GeckoView I only see the HTML popup (which tells me to give permission) but no way to grant permission.

Comment: How about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47410311/3641067) ? Check the manifest content of that, you might try adding those permissions that are related to the microphone

Answer (score 2):

GeckoView itself does not show any permission dialogs. However it provides a delegate for it that you can implement yourself: `GeckoSession.setPromptDelegate()`.

You basically have to do two things:

1. Request a permission from the Android system if needed by implementing `GeckoSession.PermissionDelegate.onAndroidPermissionsRequest()`.
2. Process the content permission request from the website by implementing `GeckoSession.PermissionDelegate.onContentPermissionRequest()` - which comes down to calling `grant()` or `reject()` on the provided `callback` object.

The [Mozilla's Android Components](https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/android-components) project provides implementations for this and many other "browser features" on top of GeckoView - if you do not want to have a custom implementation. Browsers like "[Firefox Preview](https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/fenix)" use the implementations from this project.